# How to convert Ajax serialized dates to date format in sencha touch

Tags: datetime, sencha-touch

I am building an App using Sencha touch api. 
I have a model

```
Ext.regModel('Task',
    {fields: [{name:'TaskID', type:'int'}, 
             {name:'DueDate', type:'date'},
             {name:'ClientName', type:'string'},
             {name:'TaskName', type:'string'},
             {name:'AssignedTo', type:'string'}]
});
```

I recieve a date `/Date(1304879400000)/` i.e Ajax serialized date. So how do i convert into readable date format. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use a converter in the model config:

```
fields: [
    'id'
    {
        name: 'datetime',
        type: 'date',
        dateFormat: 'MS'
    }
```

The above model has two fields: *id* and *datetime*, with *datetime* being parsed as a Microsoft serialised Ajax string.

See docs for [dateFormat](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-dateFormat) and the ['MS' format](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Date).

Answer (score 0):

The number is the timestamp so you could parse it like:

```
 date = new Date(parseInt(DueDate.substr(6)));
```

Where DueDate is your `"/Date(1304879400000)/"` formatted string

Comment: So how do i convert within model itself?